# Combining regex with $in operator in mongodb

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I'm building regex queries for mongo

```py
        s_list = [f"/^.*{x}.*/i" for x in s_list]
        print(s_list)
        query: dict = resumes_collection.find({
            "first_name": {
                "$in": s_list
            },
        })
```

This regex is supposed to get all data regardless of case sensitivity
etc if we have `loop` in the database
if we enter `^.*OP.*/i` or `^.*oO.*/i` will return `loop` in either case
Currently this returns nothing.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/
Docs for reference. Using motor to interact with mongodb, motor runs pymongo under the hood

Comment: You do not need `[f"/^.*{x}.*/i" for x in s_list]`. Remove the first line and try `"first_name": { "$regex": re.compile("|".join(s_list), re.I) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
query: dict = resumes_collection.find({
            "first_name": {
                "$regex": re.compile("|".join(s_list), re.I)
            },
        })
```

Notes:

- The `[f"/^.*{x}.*/i" for x in s_list]` generates a list of strings that are meant to be parsed as regex, but the `$in` operator will treat them as strings
- `/.../` regex literal notation is not supported in Python, you need to define a regex object using `re.compile`
- `"|".join(s_list)` generates a single pattern out of all the `s_list` strings joining them with a `|`  OR operator. You do not need to match the whole string, adding `.*` on both sides is not necessary and does more harm in fact.